# How can I print JIT compilation logs to the specified log file in Java 11/17?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

For printing Java JIT compilation logs, I have now used some jvm parameters.But there is no content in the compilation.log.

The jvm parameters I have now used:

```
-XX:+PrintCompilation -Xlog:compilation*=info:file=compilation.log:time,uptime,level,tags
```

I want to print the JIT logs with the timestamp.

Thank you for your help first!

Comment: Replace “info” with “debug”. I don’t think that the old option `-XX:+PrintCompilation` is relevant to the unified logging configuration.

Comment: You're right. I just need to replace “info” with “debug”.
My service records the logs rightly now. Thank you very much!